# (How) Can I make this Array code look better? (Codingbat - Array-1 sum2)

Tags: java, arrays, simplify

I'm new to this forum and to programming and I have my first question :)

The objective is to return the sum of the first two integers in the array. My solution is in the picture I've added. Is there a way to solve this with less if cases? (I know I did not have to do the for loop, but I just learned it and wanted to try it out :D)

Thank you for all answers!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx06s.png

Edit: Here's my code:

```
public int sum2(int[] nums) {

  int sum = 0;

  if(nums.length == 0){
    return sum;
  }

  if(nums.length == 1){
    return nums[0];
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    sum += nums[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: _"My solution is in the picture I've added"_ -- Please don't add pictures of code.  If you have code you'd like us to look at, please include it as formatted text in your question.

Comment: Hey Kenny, here is a helpful post to understand how to add your code in the StackOverflow question you posted above as per the recommendations above.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: You don't actually need any conditional statements (you could just do something like `for (int i=0; i<2 && i < nums.length; i++) { sum += nums[i]; }`, but it's generally much easier to read code where the logical branches are separated into their own statements.

Comment: or just one line  `return nums.length == 0 ? 0 : nums.length == 1 ? nums[0] : nums[0] + nums[1];`

Answer (score 3):

you can use limit() method in stream

```
 public long sum2(int[] nums) {
      return Arrays.stream(nums).limit(2).sum();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it in this simple way:

```
public int sum2(int[] nums) {

    if (nums.length == 0)
        return 0;

    if (nums.length == 1)
        return nums[0];

    return nums[0] + nums[1];
}
```

You can't remove the two `if` statements form the code, unless you want to unnecessarily complicate it, for example, as @axurefrog wrote in his comment:

```
public int sum2(int[] nums) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length && i < 2; i++)
        sum += nums[i]; 

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this without if-else headache

```java
public int sum2(int[] nums)                                                     
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length && i < 2; i++) sum+=nums[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Edit: 
    Adding `i < nums.length` in for loop condition to take care of empty array as per comment from Luca Murra

Comment: In this way, if the array is empty, it'll throw an `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: I was more focused on simplifying the logic, not really into fixing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the sum of the first n value of the array:

```
public int sum(int[] arr, int n) {
    int sum  = 0;
    int num = Math.min( arr.length, n );
    for( int i=0; i < num; i++ ) {)
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative solutions which somewhat look "better":

- `sum2()` with `switch` so *no if* statements
- `sum3()` with `nested ternary` expressions, makes it very short.

It's good practice to avoid multiple `return` so you can keep the *single entry - simple exit point* of the algorithm, supporting debugging.

I've left the snippet wrapped up so you can try them by a single copy/paste.

```java
public class Main{

    public static int sum2(int[] nums) {

        int sum = 0;

        switch (nums.length) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                sum = nums[0];
                break;
            default:
                sum = nums[0] + nums[1];
                break;
        }

        return sum;
    }


    public static int sum3(int[] nums) {

        return nums.length == 1 ? nums[0] : nums.length >= 2 ? nums[0] + nums[1] : 0;
    }


    public static void main(String []args){

        int[] nums1 = {11, 13, 1, 0};   // expected: 24
        int[] nums2 = {3};              // expected: 3
        int[] nums3 = {};               // expected: 0

        System.out.println("sum2: " + sum2(nums1));
        System.out.println("sum2: " + sum2(nums2));
        System.out.println("sum2: " + sum2(nums3));
        System.out.println(' ');
        System.out.println("sum3: " + sum3(nums1));
        System.out.println("sum3: " + sum3(nums2));
        System.out.println("sum3: " + sum3(nums3));

    }
}
```

The output:

```
sum2: 24                                                                                                                                   
sum2: 3                                                                                                                                    
sum2: 0                                                                                                                                    

sum3: 24                                                                                                                                   
sum3: 3                                                                                                                                    
sum3: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Java8` or above, and want to have a more generic solution (meaning sum of N numbers) you can use streams as follow:

```
public long sum2(int[] nums) {
    return Arrays.stream(nums).sum();
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly answering the question, but I guess it's enough related to be worth pointing out.